# Where to find a log of identity specification skipping rows

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I have a Microsoft SQl server 2005 database with a table whose primary key has the identity specification is set to yes to auto increment.

Recently the primary key skipped two numbers(which I understand is normal as they are not necessarily sequential).

However I would like to find out, if possible, why they skipped and when, i.e. if a stored procedure rollback occured and the primary key sequence didn't rollback or they were deleted somehow.

My question is, does Microsoft SQL server management studio have a **designated** area that stored records such as this, i.e. transaction logs etc for me to have a look at to try and determine why this skip happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your code log it there is no record. So no: SQL Server does not take note of this.

A transaction rollback or an INSERT error (which is a single statement rollback) will generate gaps in the number sequence. SQL Server does not take note of this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an IDENTITY that increments by 1 each time, then you will see haps in your ids if a ROLLBACK occurs - in the event of a rollback, the IDENTITY value will *not* be reverted back so the ID value it assigned for that operation will essentially be lost. This is entirely normal behaviour.

Suppose you have a high volume of INSERTs, in the event of one insert failing/rolling back, then rolling back the IDENTITY value increment would be a nightmare as there could have been a whole swathe of INSERTs in the mean time.

Comment: Hi, yes it increments by 1 in this case. its a very low volume of inserts, is there anywhere to find a record or a log of why it happened? thanks